# close the total application will closed when we click on home in any activity

Tags: android

close the total application will closed when we click on home in any activity and again start the application from starting onwards (Starting Activity).In my application activities contain back button also.For this Give me some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should re-write you question to make it more understandable. I personally didn't understand what you have and what you want.

Comment: How is a user supposed to exit your application if pressing home always restarts it?

Comment: I think he means when someone presses home, quit back to the original activity, then when it next starts start from this original activity again

Answer (score 1):

Have an activity that extends application, in here you need two flag's.

> [Declaring Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
         public static boolean flagForHome= false;
         public static boolean flagForChangingActivity= false;

  }
```

Then in onPause and onResume of each activity

> [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

```
    public void onResume(){                  
            if(flagForHome && !flagForChangingActivity){
                finish();
            } else {
                MyApplication.flagForHome= false;
                MyApplication.flagForChangingActivity= false;
            }
    }

    public void onPause(){                  
            MyApplication.flagForHome= true;
    }
```

Finally when changing activity normally using startActivity(); you will need to set the flagForChangingActivity to true;

> [Using Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

```
   MyApplication.flagForChangingActivity= true;       
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

this will stop your app closing when changing activity (as the activity going into the background will hit onPause and the new activity starting up will hit onResume)

Don't forget in your home activity to set the flag back to false. This will stop your app instantly closing itself when you start it the second time!

HomeActivity.class:

```
  public void onPause(){                  
            Application.flagForHome= false;
    }
```

*EDIT*

Start Activity for Result is just the same procedure:

```
 MyApplication.flagForChangingActivity= true;       
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: did u understand my question or not?

Comment: @Pinki Your original question? Yes I have given you an answer, is that not what you wanted?

Comment: In my application i have so many activities ,some activity are started with startactivityForResult().in that situation above code face one problem

Comment: @Pinki No it wouldn't. startActivityForeResult is just the same procedure See Edit